# How to display component inside another component and navigate between by using vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-router

I managed to implement the project on Vue. Now there are some other problems occured. I want this dashboard to be a single page application. Now I have four main components in the main page which are Navbar.vue, Sidebar.vue, Content.vue and Footer.vue

There is no problem and I can use all of them in the App.vue but for now my Content.vue component is empty and I want some contents to be appear in that blank content page when the user clicks the links from the sidebar. I know that I need to use vue-router at this point. I have no problem implementing and using vue-router but I am not able to display my content in the Content.vue component.

Here is my App.vue looks like

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Navbar></Navbar>
    <Sidebar></Sidebar>
    <Content></Content>
    <Footer></Footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from './components/Navbar.vue'
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar.vue'
import Content from './components/Content.vue'
import Footer from './components/Footer.vue'


export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Sidebar,
    Content,
    Footer
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried to put the tags in tags and arranged the vue-router based as follows;

```
import Chart from "./components/charts/Chart";

export const routes = [
    { path : '/chart', component : Chart}
];
```

I also arranged the main.js file so there is no problem using vue-router for sure. For the test part I created a Chart.vue component and put a div and a paragraph inside of it. I am currently working on localhost and I thought that I can display the Chart.vue component inside Content.vue component by addressing http://localhost:8080/chart. But the app still gives me my main page. What am I missing?

Comment: Putting <route-view> tags inside of <Content></Content> did not work.

Comment: The other components(Navbar,Sidebar,Footer) are working?

To use the router you have created u must  use <router-view></router-view> in <div id=app></div

Comment: All the components are working, the page looks exactly as it should be. I just want to other contents like Charts, Graphs etc to appear in the Content.vue so I thought it is the correct way putting <router-view></router-view> inside <Content></Content> So what should I do? I have a Chart.vue file and there are some stuff inside but I can't display them inside my Content.vue

Comment: One possible way to do what you want is to use only <router-view></router-view> in <div id=app></div>,then set to the routes Chart.vue and all the other stuffs(Navigation,content... are not needed).And use Navbar,  Sidebar,Content  and Footer inside your components(Chart.vue,etc) which are mentioned in routes.

Comment: So when the path is '/' I should load my main components     { path : '', component : 'Navbar'}, like this and in the App.vue there will be only <router-view></router-view> but when the path is /chart I will load the Chart.vue component. Is it correct?

Comment: Between your pages(Charts.vue, etc)(Not Navbar,Sidebar,Content,Footer), you want to change only the content and all the others stay the same?

Comment: Exactly. I want them to be seperated because for the entire project, Navbar, Sidebar and Footer will remain the same and they will be needed. For now the Content part is the blank part, the middle part of the website let's say. I only want to change the Content.vue when user clicks a link from the Sidebar, I want my charts, graphs, statistics tables etc to appear on my Content.vue. I tried to add the Navbar, Sidebar, Content and Footer when the path is "/" but it only displays the first one that it sees. So is there a way to represent them as root components all together?

Answer (score 0):

You imported vue-router in main.js??

Something like:

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter)

Comment: Yes I did. I also created a routes.js file and also imported that in main.js as well. Also I did that Vue.use(VueRouter); too. 
Is it okay to use like; 

<Content>
<router-view></router-view>
</Content>

Comment: I think you should only use <router-view></router-view> and put the content component as root in router: { path : '/', component : Content}

Comment: I just did what you said     { path : '', component : 'Navbar'},
    { path : '', component : 'Sidebar'},
    { path : '', component : 'Content'},
    { path : '', component : 'Footer'} l
but when I do that it gives me error 'Navbar' is defined but never used   no-unused-vars

Comment: No, in the router you put only the components that changes in your page. In <router-view> it will change to <Content> or <Chart> depending on the route you are. You shall not put Navbar or Footer there

Answer (score 0):

You dont need content component. Your content component will be replaced by your routes.
And your routes will be something like this:

```
{ path : '/chart', component : Chart}
{ path : '/whateverPageYouWant', component: WhateverPageYouWant}
```

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Navbar></Navbar>
    <Sidebar></Sidebar>
    <router-view><router-view>
    <Footer></Footer>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Navbar from './components/Navbar.vue'
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar.vue'
import Content from './components/Content.vue'
import Footer from './components/Footer.vue'


export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Sidebar,
    Footer
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: I got it. Try to do that now. I will let you know. Thank you.

Comment: I did as you said. Now I do not have a Content component. I put a Chart component as you said and it worked. Now when the link is ocalhost:8081/chart it gives me what I want. But there is a little problem. When I was using Content.vue, there were breadcrumbs inside of it. Now that I don't have that component, where should I put the breadcrumbs?

Comment: You can use it in <div id=app></div> as you did with navbar,sidebar or inside each route component

Comment: https://resminiz.com/r/ow1s can you check the current version of it? The charts are all under the sidebar when I don't use Content? What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried to put the sidebar component inside charts?

Comment: No I haven't but I think I need a container to wrap the <router-view></router-view> becasue I still don't know what the contents will be. Every time I add a content, should I put the sidebar and everything? I think having a container or something like that can fix my problem. Because it looks pretty bad right now https://resminiz.com/r/ocMu